# Marklogic Node API - how to filter the results from a valuesBuilder

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I want to retrieve all documents in my MarkLogic db that have month=November and also group them by name, and get the count of records per name. I know I can get the frequency per name by using valuesBuilder with a range index on the name field, but how can I filter this result so that I only get the count of records for the month of November?

Supposedly valuesBuilder.fromIndexes().where() can do the filtering, but I don't know what to pass here and examples online seem to be sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API doc](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/valuesBuilder.BuiltQuery.html#where), the where clause takes a queryBuilder.query. With that in mind, you should be able to do something like this (not tested):

```
var marklogic = require('marklogic');
var vb = marklogic.valuesBuilder;
var qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;
vb
  .fromIndexes()
  .where(qb.value('month', 'November'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying before to pass qb.byExample to pass to where, but apparently that doesn't work for some reason (I assumed qb.byExample and qb.value returned the same type of thing)

Comment: Query By Example doesn't work in the Values Builder.  That would be a sensible RFE issue, which you could file on the GitHub repository.